# 3rd party Dart packages in pubspec.yaml lead to fatal file not found error in Xcode (but works on Android)

Tags: xcode, android-studio, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am developing a Flutter app in Android Studio on a MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave. The app compiles and runs on Android (both emulator and physical device) but fails to compile for iOS (both emulator and physical device). It compiles fine for both platforms if no 3rd Dart library is referenced in pubspec.yaml.

Flutter doctor is not showing any error.

Here is my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: yr_school_bus_cancellations
description: York Region School Bus Cancellations

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  http: ^0.12.0+1
  html: ^0.13.3+3
  sqflite: ^1.1.0
  path_provider: ^0.5.0+1
  url_launcher: ^5.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

And the error message in Xcode:

```
=== BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled, and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting to "Default" for the "Runner" target.
=== BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
/Users/josephlam/AndroidStudioProjects/2019/yr_school_bus_cancellations/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: fatal error: 'path_provider/PathProviderPlugin.h' file not found
#import <path_provider/PathProviderPlugin.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

PathProvider is not the only package causing the issue. If I remove the reference to PathProvider in pubspec.yaml, then the build will fail on another 3rd party package (i.e. http, url_launcher, sqflite).

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `flutter clean`?

Comment: Check if adding `use_frameworks!` helps https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16049#issuecomment-382629492

Comment: Thanks, folks. I tried both suggestions but the issue persists.

Comment: Try `pod install` in `ios/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Günter Zöchbauer, the following article fixed the issue for me: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#generated-project-files-outdated.

Below is a replication of the content from the article:

When a project is created with flutter create foo several files in the ios/ and android/ sub-directories are created.

Newer Flutter versions might generate these files a bit differently and projects created with older Flutter versions might cause issues.

- Delete the ios/ and android/ directories and run flutter create . to re-generate these directories.

Custom changes will be lost and need to be re-applied. This is easiest if the project is committed to a version control system like Git.